# How to add span.required element in label, if input has required attribute?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is it possible to add `<span class="required">*</span>` in label element, if the input field has required attribute?

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="customer_phone">Email:</label><p></p>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input type="text" id="b_customer_email" class="form-control" size="40" value="<?php echo get_user_meta (get_current_user_id(),'b_customer_email',true);?>" name="b_customer_email" required>
    </div>
</div>`
```

And I have tried this jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").has("[required]")function() {
        $(".control-label").after("<span class='required'>*</span>");
    };
});
```

The span element is not added after the label element.

**What should I add to the script to make it work?**

Comment: I have downvoted for not even trying to check console for obvious errors.

Comment: fair enough. The jQuery syntax is off and smell of wishful thinking

Comment: [.has()](http://api.jquery.com/has/) looks for descendant elements that match the selector - which in your case isn't what you're looking for.  You should probably use the attributes selector `$("input[required]")`

Comment: I am newbie in jquery, don't have enough stack knowledge of how to debug script, not a programmer.

Answer (score 3):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UuaJ8/). You were on the right way actually. But keep in mind that `:has` selector is not native thus not really efficient.

```
$(function() {
    $('.form-group:has(input[required]) > label.control-label')
        .after('<span class="required">*</span>')    
})
```

Comment: I have tried your code @Yury Tarabanko, and it works, span element added beside label element.
Thank you so much